# Neo4j Spatial order by distance

Tags: sorting, neo4j, spatial

I'm currently using Spatial for my queries as follows:

```
START b=node:LocationIndex('withinDistance:[70.67,12.998,6.0]')
RETURN b
ORDER BY b.score
```

B is an entity that has a score and I'd like to order by this score, but I found a case in which, all the entities with score 0 were not ordered by distance. I know Spatial automatically orders by distance, but once I force the order by another field, I lose this order.

Is there any way of forcing this order as a second order field like:

```
START b=node:LocationIndex('withinDistance:[70.67,12.998,6.0]')
RETURN b
ORDER BY b.score, ?distance?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately in the current spatial plugin, there is no cypher support at all, so the distance function (or distance result) cannot be accessed by the ORDER BY.

As you already noticed, the withinDistance function in the index itself will return results ordered by distance. If you do not add an extra ORDER BY in the cypher query, the distance order should be maintained. However, when adding the extra ORDER BY, the original order is lost. It would be an interesting feature request to the cypher developers to maintain the original order for elements that are comparatively identical in the ORDER BY.

There is also a separate plan to develop spatial functions within cypher itself, and that will solve the problem the way you want. But there is not yet any information on a development or release schedule for this.

One additional option that might help you in a shorter time frame and is independent of the neo4j development plans themselves, is to add an order by extension to the spatial index query. Right now you are specifying the index query as 'withinDistance:[70.67,12.998,6.0]', but you could edit the Spatial Plugin code to support passing extra parameters to this query, and they could be an order by parameter. Then you would have complete control of the order.

Comment: I found using cypher,  when we return the 'lat' and 'lon', it doesn't return distance order by default.. How to solve it? And if there is a way to return distance using cypher? Thanks